# Databricks command says databricks-cli isn't configured when run from Python (with os.system()) but works fine when pasted into command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, databricks

My Python code constructs a string in the form
`myCmd = 'databricks fs cp dbfs:/mnt/extracts/dsp/{}/full.xml "{}"'.format(extractId, file_path)`

This results in a string like this:
`databricks fs cp dbfs://mt/extracts/dsp/123/full.xml "c:\filepath\full.xml"`

When I attempt to run this string using `os.system(myCmd)` I'm given the following warning (either within the Python console, or in the cmd window):
`` Error: InvalidConfigurationError: You haven't configured the CLI yet! Please configure by entering `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\databricks configure ``

But when i copy and paste the constructed `myCmd` to the command prompt the databricks copy works fine.

I've tried running databricks configure then re-running the Python code, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I also had same error message in different context when dealing with `mlflow` objects
Later I observed that I was getting this error only when I install `mlflow` as
`!pip install mlflow`
instead of
`%pip install mlflow`

Answer (score 2):

This warning can also arise if you don't have a default databricks configuration profile. For example, in my `.databrickscfg` file I had two profiles, [PRO] and [DEV]. When I switched to [PRO] and [DEFAULT], everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. It said "You haven't configured the CLI yet!" from within the Python Notebook. I changed the Python version to 3 from 2 and it worked fine. Also changing the Databricks Runtime version to something like 5.5-LTS-ML fixes the issue.